# Can I define an integer in a loop only once?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is a piece of my code, I run the callback every time I press the ok button on my pop-up so I only want count to be defined once. After that I need to exclude the line "count = 0" from being looped. When I put it outside of the loop, even using global, it gives me an error saying it doesn't know what count is. Any way I could fix this? (Here is my code)

```
def callback():
    count = 0
    value = int(entry_field.get())
    entry_field.delete("0", tk.END)


    if value in plusOne:
        count += count + 1
        print(count)
```

Thanks

Comment: Not related to your original problem, but are you sure you want `count += count + 1` and not `count += 1`?

Comment: When you included `global count` inside `callback`, which *exact* exception did you get back, a `NameError`, a `UnboundLocalError` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define it as global?:

```
count = 0
def callback():
    global count
    value = int(entry_field.get())
    entry_field.delete("0", tk.END)


    if value in plusOne:
        count += count + 1
        print(count)
```